# Windows 10 "Not connected - Connections are available" and "Limited" yellow warning but Working internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, network-adapter, wifi-configuration

After upgrading my dell xps 13 (2015 model) from win8.1 to win10 all worked fine really fast top notch combination, untill after a week it now shows a yellow triangle warning icon on to of the wifi ion in the taskbar. On mouseover it says:

*`Not connected - Connections are available`*

On the list of wifi connections, under the current router it says *`Limited`*

**Now eventhough it says NOT connected, I DO have internet working!** How is this possible? Sometimes pinging google.com drops from 12ms to 110ms, perhaps this has something to do with this Limited thing? I have an Intel 7265 AC network card, with fresh drivers for windows 10 64bit version 29 july 2015. I have already tried two methods: uncheck the box for letting windows shutting down the device to save power, and I have uninstalled the drivers and restarted windows more than ten times already. Both did not help! What can I try to get this warning go away and get to full speed?

**UPDATE1:** on another location my notebook gives me the exact same warning! I think I have shut off one too many services... which one could be responsible for this? (see first image) *"The dependency service or group failed to start"*

**UPDATE2**: After enabling various disabled services, the yellow warning has dissapeared, and under the current wifi ssid it says *`Connected`* instead of *`Limited`* which is good news!  However, mouseovering the taskbar icon still says *`Not connected - Connections are available`* ???

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have access, try rebooting your router. I didn't see if you had done that or not.  Also you may get limited connectivity if your router requires an encryption password or other authentication and it was entered incorrectly.

Try using another wireless access point. If another AP works then you may have found an AP that is not working correctly.

Too many users on the network or a bad connection upstream can cause those symptoms.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion +1. Shut off the router, waited 10min, started the router, exact same problem unfortunately i have the feeling this is software related. PLease see my last updated sentence! Another home with wifi gives me the exact same warning. Must have to to with my win10 / services!

Answer (score 1):

Try to troubleshoot your connection, right click the wifi icon at the taskbar then click troubleshoot problem, it should solve many connection problem.

Comment: +1 for suggestion. Done that but no porblems could be detected.

Comment: Please check your WLAN AutoConfig at services console, set it at automatic and make sure the status is running, to open services console press win+r, type "services.msc" without quote and press enter.

Answer (score 1):

Complement to all the other remarks made before ...

What you can do is to test the download and upload speed by using following link : www.speedtest.net

Then there is an other great tool which is WinMTR, an free downloadable network diagnostic TOOL
http://winmtr.net/download-winmtr/

You should also run the command line Editor (cmd) as Administrator and try following command:

ping -n 100 google.com

and see if you are loosing packets ...

All this tests will allow you to check your connection.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by disabling all power management features in the system device management driver properties window, power management tab, clear the checkbox and disable power management for your network adaptor